# display the tabBar of a GXT Tabpanel to other containers

Tags: gwt, gxt, tabpanel

I have a GXT TabPanel and would like to hide the tabBar and disable the tabBar to other container.
Now I have hidden the tabBar by set height 0px:
***getBar(this.getElement()).setHeight(0)***

But how to display tabBar to other containers I do not know how to solve the problem。

When i see the source of TabPanelTemplates

```html
<div class="{style.tab}">
    <div class="{style.tabBar}">
        <div class="{style.tabStripWrap}">
            <ul class="{style.tabStrip}">
                <li class="{style.tabEdge}"></li>
                <div class="x-clear"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="{style.tabStripSpacer}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="{style.tabBody}"></div>
</div>
```

I  try to get the div class="{style.tabBar}", and display the part to other container,but i do not know how to do it.
I do not know if this idea is correct. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I try to display the tabBar to other container like this :

```html
conter.getElement().insertFirst(new SafeHtml() {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Override
   public String asString() {
    return getAppearance().getBar(ex).getInnerHTML();
   }
  });
```

---

Now the bar is visiable ,but the event is not available